# Best way to guarantee single sqlite instance when using Service, BroadcastReceiver and Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, android-sqlite

We've got a single connection to our sqlite database that we need to use between BroadcastReceivers, Services and Activites. What is the best way to do this? I am aware that we use should use a ContentProvider when we need to share data with other apps but that's not what we need to do. I've subclassed Application and using a static method to return a single instance of the Application object and then access the singleton database object. Is that the way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay it seems the documentation is clear on this. An Application instance gets created and onCreate() gets called before any broadcastreceiver / service or activity gets created. So I could continue using the singleton database objected created by the Application subclass.